# Can't use my own user with git via apache/php

Tags: php, git, apache

We are working with a legacy php project and trying to pull/push files via apache/php/git.

I'm trying to use git via shell_exec, but it throws this error:

```
warning: unable to access '/var/lib/apache2/.gitconfig': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/var/lib/apache2/.config/git/config': Permission denied
```

I have apache configured to use my own user/group and when I exec:

```
echo shell_exec('whoami');
```

It shows my own user.

I think git is trying to use apache user with no reason.

When I use git in console it works normally.

The server is an old SUSE:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.10 (Linux/SUSE)
PHP 5.2.14
```

How I can use git with my user via apache/php?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe shell_exec is changing the value of `$HOME` in the env?

Comment: I'm going to check it, thank you @Jay

Comment: @Jay this is correct with `echo shell_exec("echo \$HOME");` it throws `/var/lib/apache2 `

Comment: Okay. I guess you could see if you can change the HOME var to match the configured user; in the config of apache or php. I'm not sure where current "HOME" comes from. Alternatively I guess you could run git with custom environment `shell_exec('env HOME=/home/<yourUserName> git ...')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this old SUSE distro with apache 2.2, I changed **HOME** var of the init script:
**/etc/init.d/apache2**

```
#...
#: ${homedir:=/var/lib/$pname}
#...
#HOME=$homedir
HOME=/home/administrator
#...
```

Thank you @Jay